# raspberry pi analog audio + GPIO leds pi-blaster

Tags: raspberry-pi, sensors, gpio

I'm using pi-blaster to control LEDs connected to raspberry pi and have the following cases:

motion sensor detects change and Pi app opens audio file and LED color:

1) audio via HDMI (monitor with speakers) works fine

2) audio connected via jack outputs just noise, LEDs still working.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

do you use the built in PMW? I read that it interferes with audio on the pi.

try [pi-blaster](https://github.com/sarfata/pi-blaster) with --pcm option